# mean of a column based on the index and another 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
d = {'day': [0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2], 'period': ['p1','p1','op1','op1','p2','p2','p1','p1','op1','op1','p2','p2','p1','p1','op1','op1','p2','p2'], 's1':[2,2,3,6,4,2,8,2,1,2,1,2,2,9,5,2,2,3]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

And i need this result:

[image]

I tried this:

```
df.groupby('period', as_index=False)['s1'].mean()
```

Here is its result:

[image]

But it doesn't solve my problem..

Comment: You need to separate your dataframe into odd and even index. Is that what as_index=False suppose to do ? I'm not sure.. Anyway, give the result of ```df.groupby('period', as_index=False)['s1'].mean()```

Comment: So yeah you did the mean of the full dataframe, while the result you want is the mean of the value of even and odd indexes in your dataframa. You can check that you indeed did that cos' (4.00+4.33)/2=4.166, (3.00+3.33)/2=3.1666 and (2.333+2.333)/2=2.33

Comment: Not necessarily even and odd I have a big df with a lot of values as p1 and p2 etc. This is just a sample df to simplify the question..

Comment: Oh ok, so you need to take into account that you don't wanna count values of the same 'period' the same 'day'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df.groupby(['period',df.groupby(['day','period']).cumcount()]).mean()
```

Output:

```
          day        s1
period                 
op1    0  1.0  3.000000
       1  1.0  3.333333
p1     0  1.0  4.000000
       1  1.0  4.333333
p2     0  1.0  2.333333
       1  1.0  2.333333
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, in order to sort it I had to rename the indexes and sort it by sort_index(): 

df = df.rename(index={'op1"': "B", 'p1': "A", 'p2': "C"})
  Then
df.sort_index()

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a column which groups every second value.  Then `groupby()` that.

```
d = {'day': [0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2], 'period': ['p1','p1','op1','op1','p2','p2','p1','p1','op1','op1','p2','p2','p1','p1','op1','op1','p2','p2'], 's1':[2,2,3,6,4,2,8,2,1,2,1,2,2,9,5,2,2,3]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dfm = df.assign(
    even=lambda dfa: dfa.index%2
).groupby(["period","even"]).mean().reset_index().drop(columns="even")

print(dfm.to_string())
```

**output**

```
  period  day        s1
0    op1  1.0  3.000000
1    op1  1.0  3.333333
2     p1  1.0  4.000000
3     p1  1.0  4.333333
4     p2  1.0  2.333333
5     p2  1.0  2.333333
```